# Listening for URL changes in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

Is there a way to listen for URL changes/redirects in Puppeteer? For example if I point the browser to `http://www.somesite.com/home` and it redirects to `http://www.somesite.com/login`, I would like a way to observe these changes and then terminate the current action.

I tried this:

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
    console.log(interceptedRequest.url());
    interceptedRequest.continue();
});
```

but this is just all the requests. It doesn't log when the url changes.

Comment: you should use response instead and check the status code for a 301/302

Comment: Also, maybe [`httpRequest.redirectChain()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#httprequestredirectchain) can help.

Answer (score 10):

How about

```
page.on("framenavigated", frame => {
    const url = frame.url(); // the new url
    
    // do something here...
});
```